Get the file extension from byte array
Below is the code snippet to get the file extension
public static Map<String, String> getImageType(byte[] imageContent) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
        MediaType mediaType = config.getMimeRepository().detect(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageContent), new Metadata());
        MimeType mimeType = config.getMimeRepository().forName(mediaType.toString())
        result.put("extn", mimeType.getExtension().replaceFirst(".", ""));
        return result;
    }

tika-core dependency used version 1.13
Above code is working fine for all the document having extension .pdf, .jpg, .csv, .txt, .bin, .jpeg and return expected extension Ex {extn=.pdf},  But it is not working when the file extension is .doc and .docx and return blank {extn=}
Expecting to get the .doc and .docx file extension ex:{extn=.doc}

What are MediaType and MimeType values found in these cases?


In case of .doc file getting application/x-tika-msoffice for both mediaType and mimeType
In case of .pdf file getting application/pdf in both mediaType and mimeType


Try both a newer version of Apache Tika, and including the container-aware detectors from the Parsers package?
